# Conversion date time from string converting to 01-01-0001

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

the field is as a nvarchar in the table, and i am getting the date from calendar picker dd-MM-yyyy . I am saving the data in table using below statement

```
 DateTime dtn = new DateTime();
  DateTime.TryParse(txtPrevFromDate.Text, new CultureInfo("en-GB", true), DateTimeStyles.None, out dtn);
    objKYT.Str_PrevFromDate = dtn.ToString();
```

After converting the data the date is as `11/30/2017 12:00:00 AM`. But when i am converting this data to display this convert in to `01/01/0001` . Below is the statement i am using

```
DateTime dtydt5 = new DateTime();
DateTime.TryParse(objKYT.Str_PrevFromDate, new CultureInfo("en-GB", true), DateTimeStyles.None, out dtydt5);
 lblPrevFrom.Text = dtydt5.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

can you please tell me how can i resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse fails and `dtydt5` is never overridden, because `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`. It is prefererable to always use `ParseExact` and in such a way explicitly tell what format is expected:

```
dtydt5 = DateTime.ParseExact("11/30/2017 12:00:00 AM", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This statement returns `30/11/2017` which is what you are searching for I guess

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, then you want the date with time format. If yes, then you can use the below code snippet.

```
        DateTime dtn = new DateTime();
        DateTime.TryParse("20-05-1993", new CultureInfo("en-GB", true), DateTimeStyles.None, out dtn);
        var st = dtn.ToString();

        DateTime dtydt5 = new DateTime();
        DateTime.TryParse(st, new CultureInfo("en-GB", true), DateTimeStyles.None, out dtydt5);
        var st1 = dtydt5.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```